# Difference between "get hands on" and "get"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Can anybody explain the difference between "*getting ones hands on something*" and "*getting something*"? 
Example:

> "Somehow, she got her hands on the bat."

I guess she suddenly found/fumbled the bat. Is that right?

Comment: What has your research told you? Searching the [idiom's meaning](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+hands+on) and [*get*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/get)'s meaning, shows you that they are synonymous.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

***Get something*** means to obtain, purchase or receive something.

***To get your hands on something*** can have a very wide range of meanings, frequently colloquial and certainly context sensitive:

*If I get my hands on you*, would be used as a threat.
*I'd love to get my hands on that car*, Oh how I would like to drive that car.
*I could fix it if only I could get my hands on a screwdriver.*

*Does anyone know where I can get my hands on a ticket for the concert?* means that I need a ticket and am asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

**Get** **(getting something)**
means to obtain, to acquire, to take into possession, to be given, to receive, etc.

It can be specific and refer to something *concrete*:

- ***He went home to get his catcher's mitt.***
- ***They decided to stop and get dinner.***

Or it can refer to something more *abstract*:

- ***On Sundays, she'll often get depressed.***
- ***He was afraid he would get sick.***

---

**Getting one's hands on** is a strictly defined type of **get**, one that implies a certain level of determination, desperation and-or ineptitude. It communicates a more frantic, physically aggressive type of acquisition:

- ***She loved to fantasize about getting her hands on a million dollars***.
- ***He knew eventually he would get his hands on that rare comic book***.

---

In the case of the example sentence, it's more fumbled than found. **"Somehow"** denotes something that's preventing previous attempts to get at bat. The fact that she's there now—that she actually **got her hands on** that bat—is just plain hard-to-believe, a fluke.